# Missing() method DateHistogramAggregationDescriptor doesn't seems to work in a specific condition

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I need to be able to yield the following query using NEST:

```
GET /blabla/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "groupby": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "CLOSED_DATE",
        "interval": "month",
        "format": "yyyyMM",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "time_zone": "UTC",
        "missing": "100001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The obstacule to get there is the missing method. It recieves, as a parameter, the replacement for the missing value. Therefore, I came up with this code:

```
return a => a.DateHistogram(level.ToString(), dh => dh
 .Field(param.Item1)                                                            
 .Interval(param.Item2)                                                                  
 .Format(param.Item3)                                                                  
 .TimeZone(timeZone)                                                                  
 .MinimumDocumentCount(minimumDocumentCount)                                                                  
 .Missing(new DateTime()));
```

Unfortunately, it doesn;t work as it actually generates this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "groupby": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "CLOSED_DATE",
        "interval": "month",
        "format": "yyyyMM",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "time_zone": "UTC",
       "missing": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently, the format is the issue here.
How can I work around that?

Cheers!

Comment: What is `100001` supposed to be in the context of a date?

Comment: @Val January in the year 1000? :)

Comment: No kidding @RussCam ;-)

Comment: What is the ES version which you were using?

Comment: Hi guys,

I'm using this "format": "yyyyMM", so the "100001" value is just for me to spot the missing terms. It works all right, the problem actually is trying to use NEST.NET to produce it.

Im using Es 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the client; [I have added an issue to address this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2864).

In the meantime, you can workaround this by specifying the format as

```
 .Format(param.Item3 + "||date_optional_time")
```

such that Elasticsearch can deserialize a serialized `DateTime` in the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`